# Date slicer with 'between' option not working on published dashboard but working on report tab

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am having problems with a date slicer on our PowerBI dashboard. This slicer worked properly till yesterday, October 28th, 2021, however it is no longer operating as planned (below is the screenshot).

The problem only occurs on published PowerBI dashboards, however everything works well on the report tab. The underlying data(dates) is likewise correct.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was at Power BI Cloud end, They have resolved it by deploying a patch for it.